# How to reshape this dataframe in R program

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe like below sample:

```
      A    B    C   
[1,] "A1" "B3" "C1"
[2,] "A2" "B1" "C2"
[3,] "A3" "B3" "C3"
[4,] "A1" "B2" "C3"
[5,] "A3" "B3" "C2"
[6,] "A1" "B1" "C1"
```

And I would like to reshape it like this, to expand every unique value of variables to a single variable, and mark 1/0 in the value field. Above data frame shall be reshaped to this:

```
     A    B1    B2    B3    C1    C2    C3       
[1,] "A1" "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0" 
[2,] "A2" "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0" 
[3,] "A3" "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "1" 
[4,] "A1" "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1" 
[5,] "A3" "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "1"   "0" 
[6,] "A1" "1"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"
```

The real data is in huge amount (>100 thousand per day, and much more fields and unique values. So I need a high efficiency program instead of using for...

I believe you could help... I am a beginner, only know for... :(

Comment: Are you sure this is a `data.frame`? The output you have shown looks more like a matrix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1],  mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1]))))
#    A B3 C1 B1 C2 C3 B2
#V1 A1  1  1  0  0  0  0
#V2 A2  0  0  1  1  0  0
#V3 A3  1  0  0  0  1  0
#V4 A1  0  0  0  0  1  1
#V5 A3  1  0  0  1  0  0
#V6 A1  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: it does not give the desired output, desired output is `cbind(df1[, "A"], mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[, -1]))))` or if we want to be rigourous: `cbind(A=df1[, "A"], mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[, -1])))[, c(3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5)])` and no explanation whatsoever...

Comment: FWIW, the answer is not correct.

Comment: There is no `A1`, `A2` and `A3` in the desired output. That's how.

Comment: Cath already gave you the correct answer. But it's a dupe (of your own answer) anyway.

Comment: You have 10 columns, desired output has 7.

Comment: The `cbind` and subsetting is literally the only difference with the dupe target. You can't reopen the question and then say it is irrelevant. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too (with `base R`):

```
df <- cbind(as.character(df$A), model.matrix(~B+C+0,df,list(B=contrasts(df$B, contrasts=F), 
                                                      C=contrasts(df$C, contrasts=F))))
dimnames(df) <- list(NULL, c('A', paste0('B',1:3), paste0('C',1:3)))
df
 #      A    B1  B2  B3  C1  C2  C3 
 #[1,] "A1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0"
 #[2,] "A2" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0"
 #[3,] "A3" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1"
 #[4,] "A1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1"
 #[5,] "A3" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0"
 #[6,] "A1" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0"
```

Comment: Thanks all... the first answer (very quick) showed me the correct way even the final result is a little different vs desired~ anyway it's a sample~ so I think I have caught the point- thanks @akrun
and other answers are getting more and more precise, I appreciate your help so much as a beginner (and not good in english). Now i am studying other solutions with great thanks~ @->-